# Sencha touch: Use HTTP status codes instead of {"success":true}

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, sencha-touch, extjs

I'm building a restful Sencha Touch app backed by a rails app and am having a little trouble getting them to play nice.

Sencha seems to be ignoring HTTP status codes, and instead is dependent of the response having a "success" property set to true in order for it to consider the request successful.

Is there any way to override sencha to use HTTP status codes instead of the "success" property?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have some code as an example? If you use a raw Ext.Ajax request you can give it a callback function that will be called no matter what happens with the request. That should be bare metal enough for anything. http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.Ajax-method-request

Let me give you some advice though and try not to fight the Ext API too much. It will really make your life more difficult in the long run.